# Logit and ClassLog(): how to classify a larger dataframe?

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression

I am running a Logit model using a sample from my data, but when I try to run the `ClassLog` function to classify my cases in the original dataframe I get an error:

```
Error in table(predict(MOD, type = "response") > cut, resp) : 
all arguments must have the same length
```

This is my reproducible example:

```
set.seed(25)
myData = data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = runif(10000), dep = c(rep(1,400),rep(0,9600)))
myData$dep = factor(myData$dep)
```

Creating a sample with the same number of `dep ==0` and `dep ==1`:

```
dep.1 = subset(myData,dep==0)
dep.2 = subset(myData,dep==1)

set.seed(30)
rows = sample(nrow(dep.1),nrow(dep.2))
dep.1 = dep.1[rows,]

mySample = rbind(dep.1,dep.2)
```

Running the logit model:

```
model = glm(data=mySample, dep~x+y,family="binomial")

library(QuantPsyc)
```

**Works** with the sample used to run the model:

```
ClassLog(MOD = model, mySample$dep,cut=0.5)
```

**Does not work** with the original data `myData`:

```
ClassLog(MOD = model, myData$dep,cut=0.5)
```

Is there any way to run ClassLog on the original (larger) dataframe? I know I can use `predict()` to get the Probability of dep == 1, but `ClassLog` offers a direct classification according to an arbitrary `cut` and a classification table, which is much more desirable to me.

Comment: You might need to include a filter for any `NA`, `NULL`, etc values.  It could also be `subset`.  Try subsetting with `myData[myData$dep == 1, ]` and see if it changes.

Comment: @Richard, using `myData[myData$dep == 1, ]` gives me the same subset. `cut` and `resp` can be found at the bottom of my question: `cut = 0.5` and `resp =mySample$dep` (which works) or `myData$dep` (which doesn't)

Comment: I get an error with the attempt to use glm: `> model = glm(data=mySample, dep~x+y,family="binomial")
Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : 
  variable 1 has no levels`  When you look at the mySample dataframe is has no observations. Note that you had levels of 1 and 0 but subsetted on 1 and 2.

Comment: My bad, @BondedDust, I forgot to change the sample part of the code. It's now fixed. Thanks for the warning. My problem should be fully reproducible now

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and figured out that the below error occurred because one of my columns had an NA value.

Error in table(predict(MOD, type = "response") > cut, resp) : 
all arguments must have the same length

I removed the records with NA values and the ClassLog() gave the desired output.

**Note:** While you are performing logistic regression using glm function it automatically excludes rows containing NA, for all the columns included in regression. However when you feed the variable containing the result of logistic regression to ClassLog() function it doesn't automatically exclude rows containing NA and gives you the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Once you look at the code for `ClassLog` the error makes complete sense. The model was created with mySample and the second argument is supposed to be a response variable or some sort of new data perhaps, which is way too long for the model.

But perhaps,....  because the code used `predict` .... you could :

```
ClassLog(MOD = model, myData,cut=0.5)   # nope failed.
```

Try:

```
 mod2 <- glm(data=myData, dep~x+y,family="binomial")
 ClassLog(MOD = mod2, myData$dep,cut=0.5)
```

Comment: your code works, but only because you built the model based on the bigger dataframe, whereas my idea is to build it based on a sample and then use the model on another dataframe that is bigger

Comment: You could predict() on the larger dataset.

Answer (score 0):

ClassLog does not handle missing data. So you have to rewrite the model after doing:

> mydata <- subset(mydata, variable_with_NA != "NA")

After that the function should work!